# can protobuffer auto fill default value for newly created object

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a problem using google protobuf, I want to create an object with default attribute value:

```
message Obj {
    required string id = 1[default=123];
}
```

When serializing the above object:

```
string s;
Obj obj;
obj.SerializeToString(&s);
```

it complains:  can't serialize becault it's missing required field id

The doc says the "default" value is used for parsing obj from string,  not for serialize to string.

Is it possible to create object with default value?

Comment: How about making the field `optional`, then you will avoid transmitting it unnecessarily?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't set the default value for the in-memory objects.

Defaults are only applied at deserialization time. `required` makes the reader error if the field is missing. So the combination of `required` and `default` is pointless.

If you want to set an in memory default, make a factory function and use that.

Comment: Right. Put another way: The only meaning of a default value is that it is the value returned by the field's getter when the field is unset. Default values are never sent on the wire. There's certainly an argument to be made that it would be useful to have default values that are sent on the wire (e.g. a `version` field specifying the client software version), but this just isn't what protobuf default values do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't serialize the default value, but you can make it an optional field. That way, When you deserialize the stream, you'll get an object where the field is missing and trying to get the value will give you the default value.

Comment: the link seems complicated.

Comment: @aj3423 Hum.. sorry the link is for the C implementation of protobuf. I remove my comment then.

Comment: @shoosh, I don't need to get value from the object, I need to serialize it to std::string, in this case the default value doesn't work, seems I need to write a helper function CreateObjAndFillDefaultValue() to create Obj and fill default values, but, any other idea?

Comment: @aj3423 why do you need to do that?

Comment: I need to create an object -> serialize it to string -> send to server.  There're lots of attributes(about 30+) that have default values.

Comment: @aj3423 Assuming the server has code generated from the same .proto, when it tries to get fields that were not set, it will get the default value.